# Spring boot App API hosted on Google cloud under a custom domain using a dispatch file, is throwing CROS from last week

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console, spring-cloud-gcp

We have a Spring-boot application hosted on Google cloud console and we have mapped a custom domain for our API, the configuration was done using a dispatch file. The application was working fine, but from last week the API calls gets random CORS problem.

when the request for domain/get-customer API fails even now, but if the page reload it might work next time. it is really random CORS issue.

What can we do to resolve this issue?

Comment: google cloud console is not a Google Cloud service. Where is hosted your application? On App Engine I guess, if you have a dispatch file, no?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, correct. it is hosted on Google App Engine.

Comment: Do you manage CORS? Do you have more input in the logs?